# Show specific range of elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 100
            [nest] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [200] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 200
            [nest] => Array
                (
                    [300] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 300
                            [nest] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [400] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 400
                            [nest] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [500] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 500
                            [nest] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [600] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 600
            [nest] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [700] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 700
            [nest] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [800] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 800
            [nest] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [900] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 900
            [nest] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I want to be able to show only 5 element at a time. How can I make a function that takes a range (`1-5` or `5-10`, etc.) and shows that range of elements from the array.

For example, the range `1-5` would show only elements `100, 200, 300, 400, and 500` from the array. Range `5-10` would show elements `500, 600, 700, 800, and 900`.

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: @quickshiftin That seems to only work for top-level elements if I'm not mistaken? Doing `array_slice($array, 0, 2)` shows elements `100` and `200` and *every element within them*, instead of just showing elements `100` and `200` alone.

Comment: If you only want to show the top level elements you'll need to strip out their children by hand one way or another. But since your elements are arrays themselves there's not really much value at the top level. Maybe as simple as nuking the 'nest' elements from the second level after an `array_slice` is what you're after?

Comment: No, I don't only want to show top level elements. *"For example, the range 1-5 would show only elements `100, 200, 300, 400, and 500` from the array. Range 5-10 would show elements `500, 600, 700, 800, and 900`."*

Comment: `array_slice` returns nested elements, did you even try it? Sorry I misread your reply to my first comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain this better. Let's say I want a range of 1-3. That means that only elements `100, 200, and 300` should show. However, `array_slice($comments, 0, 3)` is returning elements `100, 200, and *600*`. In other words, `array_slice` only works on the top-most level elements instead of actually going inside nested arrays.

Comment: 2 questions. Is your array at most 2 levels deep? and will there only ever be one key with 200, 300 etc? The function is a simple nesting of 2 foreach loops in that case.

Comment: The array can be infinitely deep. Key names are unique.

Comment: I just hooked you up with a custom slice function in my answer, let me if that's what you were after.

Comment: Take a look at my new answer, I have a feeling it's closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting it correctly, it looks like you'd need to flatten the array first, and then array_slice will work the way you want it to.

Specifically, something like this:

```
function flatten(array $array) {
  $return = array();
  array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
  return $return;
}
```

Taken from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Well said, it took me some time to realize exactly what OP was asking for lol.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are my friend

```
function customSlice(array $a, $iStartRange, $iEndRange) {
    $aRange = range($iStartRange, $iEndRange);
    $oIt    = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                  new RecursiveArrayIterator($a),
                  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $aResult = array();
    foreach($oIt as $name => $element)
        if(in_array($name, $aRange))
            $aResult[$name] = $element;

    return $aResult;
}
```

**Example**

```
$aExample = array(
    100 => array('user_id' => 100, 'nest' => array()),
    200 => array('user_id' => 200, 'nest' => array(
        300 => array('user_id' => 300, 'nest' => array()),
        400 => array('user_id' => 400, 'nest' => array()),
        500 => array('user_id' => 500, 'nest' => array())
    )),
    600 => array('user_id' => 600, 'nest' => array()),
    700 => array('user_id' => 700, 'nest' => array()),
    800 => array('user_id' => 800, 'nest' => array()),
    900 => array('user_id' => 900, 'nest' => array())
);

$aSliced = customSlice($aExample, 100, 500);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `100 * $iRange` part does?

Comment: Your keys are 100, 200 etc instead of 1, 2 etc. It's just a simple mapping. The core code is here for you though, you should be able to tweak it for your needs.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the keys can be completely different each time (they're user_ids taken from the database). :/

Comment: Then you can just use `$aRange = range($iStartRange, $iEndRange)` instead of the first `foreach`; I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I've tried `customSlice($array, 0, 5)` but it only returns 1 result. Can you show me how you got it working on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ ?

Comment: I used your example array; pasting a full example under my answer.

Comment: Yeah, per your exmaple, you don't have anything between 0 and 5.... So you need to put 0-500 for your example array. Assuming there can be id's like 1, 2, 3 ... 100, 500 etc...

Comment: That's what my original solution was accounting for w/ the `* 100` bit, but then you said no they can be any integer over 0 so I revised it.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Is there a way to instead say "I want the first 25 elements" (i.e. a range of `0-25`)? Or, "I need the elements from 25 - 50" (i.e. the elements from the 25th element to the 50th element)?

Comment: For that I would do something like flatten the array first, either with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` or an `array_walk_recurssive` call like the other answer, then `array_slice` the result.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat different from my first answer, but likely more towards what OP is after. This function flattens the array, and slices from the flattened perspective. It does the slicing inline, rather than after the flattening. Also, I've commented out but included code to strip out the `'nest'` elements in the result, otherwise there could be lots of redundant data in them. And finally, I've put some decent comments on this one. Enjoy!

```
/**
 * Slice any array based on flattened perspective.
 * @param array $a Array to slice
 * @param int $iStartRange Starting index to slice (inclusive)
 * @param int $iEndRange Ending index to slice (inclusive)
 * Return array Sliced subset of input array.
 */
function recursive_array_slice(array $a, $iStartRange, $iEndRange)
{
    // Flatten out the inbound array
    $oIt = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
               new RecursiveArrayIterator($a),
               RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $aResult = array(); // The sliced result
    $i       = 1;       // Track which element we're on
    foreach($oIt as $name => $element) {
        // Not a very rigorous check, but this filters
        // candidates down to ones we're likely looking for
        if(!is_int($name))
            continue;

        // If the current element is in the range of
        // interest, include it in the results
        if($i >= $iStartRange && $i <= $iEndRange) {
            $aResult[$name] = $element;
            // Optional if you don't want a ton of redundant
            // data in the results
            // unset($aResult[$name]['nest']);
        }   

        // Increment the count of the current element
        $i++;

        // Bail if we've gone past the range of interest
        if($i > $iEndRange)
            break;
    }

    return $aResult;
}
```